# Equivalence of the category of finitely generated left-modules and the category of finitely generated bimodules.

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, modules

Let $R$ be an associative ring with unity, $\mathcal{A}$ be the category of finitely generated left $R$-modules and $\mathcal{B}$ be the category of finitely generated $(R,R)$-bimodules.

Do the categories $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ equivalent?

By using the properties of Hom and $\otimes$ (Proposition 2.51 and Proposition 2.54 from [An Introduction to Homological Algebra](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b98977)). I think of the functor $F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$, defined by $F(X): R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \text{Hom}(X, R)$ for objects.But, I cannot imagine the other functor $G: \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these categories are typically very different.  For instance, if $R=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ then the category of finitely generated left $R$-modules has only one simple object up to isomorphism (namely $R$ itself).  On the other hand, $(\mathbb{Q}(i),\mathbb{Q}(i))$-bimodules are modules over the ring $\mathbb{Q}(i)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}(i)\cong\mathbb{Q}(i)\times\mathbb{Q}(i)$, and there are two non-isomorphic simple modules over this ring (given by the projections of $\mathbb{Q}(i)\times\mathbb{Q}(i)$ onto the two factors).